# Getting specific link from a source code Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape link from a page with lots of data.

The link I'm trying to get has this specific td (`GIS 84F`) which no other link in the page has. This is a part of the source code, it's very long so I can't cut according to location.

```
<tr class="blueRow">
<td nowrap="nowrap">GIS 84F</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/Archives/fsl/data/1288776/000130817915000157/0001308179-15-000157-index.htm" id="documentsbutton">&nbsp;Documents</a></td>
<td class="small" >Other definitive proxy statements<br />Acc-no: 0001308179-15-000157&nbsp;(34 Act)&nbsp; Size: 2 MB            </td>
<td>2015-04-23</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="/cgi-bin/browse-fsl?action=getcompany&amp;filenum=001-36380&amp;owner=exclude&amp;count=40">001-36380</a><br>15788924         </td>
```

My attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

htmlpage = urllib2.urlopen('THELINK')
soup =  BeautifulSoup(htmlpage.read())
for link in soup.findAll('GIS 84F'):
    print link.get('href')
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output that you are currently getting? It would be helpful to know what link you're trying to scrub to test the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
for link in soup.findAll('td', text='GIS 84F'):     # get the relevant tds
    parent = link.parent                            # get the parent tr
    for a in parent.findAll('a', href=True):        # get all the a tags within
        print a['href']                             # do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the html you posted, the href isn't actually in the `td` element you're looking for.

Problems with your code:

- `findAll` will not search element text, so it will not match the `td` with "GIS 84F" in it. You can correct this by using a more advanced matching function, or by calling `findAll("td")` and then checking each resulting `<td>` for `element.get_text().strip() == "GIS 84F"`, or by calling `findAll("tr")` and looking at the child `td` elements on each result.
- If `link` is the element whose contained text matches, then `link` is a `td` element with no `href`. So what you actually wanted to do was something like "once I've found the `td` containing the relevant text, get its parent element, then get the second `td` from that, then get the `href` of the contained `a` element". In code this is something like:

  ```
  link.getParent().findAll('td')[1].find('a').get('href')
  ```

Honestly, I think a better way to do this is to use a more powerful matching language like XPath, instead of doing a whole bunch of DOM operations, but it's your call.